# Manually Set Resolution on Microsoft Display Adapter

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, miracast

I have one of those Microsoft Display Adapters that I use for Miracasting. Yesterday I decided to move it from my Sony 40 Inch 1080p 60Hz tv to my AOC f22 Monitor again 1080p 60Hz. On my tv it works fine I get the full 1080p and everything works great, but on my AOC F22 it goes down to 1280x720 and looks really bad and distorted.

Is it possible to manually set the resolution on these wireless display adapters, and if so how. I am perfectly okay with resetting the monitor the adapter whatever it takes.

Comment: There is a with.does store app for the device that lets you do limited tweaks.

Comment: Windows store app

Comment: @PhillHealey At the moment the Windows Store App and the Windows Phone App do not allow changes to the resolution, they only report it.

Comment: I was under the impression it let you change it, from what I'd read. However, I've never actually used either yet. Thanks for the info.